# SVN in Hudson through a proxy in Windows

Tags: svn, proxy, continuous-integration, hudson

I'm having trouble configuring Hudson to use a proxy to connect to my SVN server. I have the proxy credentials set up in

```
.hudson\.subversion\servers
```

and I am able to checkout from the same URL using SVN at the command line AND using Tortoise under the same user that Hudson is running under.

I'm running Hudson from the command line using

```
java -jar hudson-3.1.0.war
```

I've added every combination of

```
-Dsvnkit.http.methods=Basic,Digest,Negotiate,NTLM
```

and

```
-Dsvnkit.http.sslProtocols="SSLv3"
```

that I can think of.

Every time, I get the error:

```
ERROR: Failed to check out https://{SVN URL}
org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E175002: CONNECT request failed on 'http://{PROXY URL}:80'
svn: E175002: CONNECT of '{SVN URL}:443': 407 Proxy Authentication Required ( Forefront TMG requires authorization to fulfill the request. Access to the Web Proxy filter is denied.  ) ({SVN URL})
```

I've been stuck on this for a while and haven't made any progress at all. What should I try next?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add java properties proxy settings, for http or https
you can set using export JAVA_OPTS="" or pass ass properties "java -Dproxyset=true .."

```
-Dproxyset=true 
-Dhttp.proxyHost=proxy.com -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080 
// host which will be ignored, seperated by pipe
-Dhttp.nonProxyHosts="*.foo.com*|localhost|*.test.com:*/*"
-Dhttps.proxyHost=proxy.com
-Dhttps.proxyPort=8080
-Dhttps.nonProxyHosts="*.foo.com*|localhost|*.test.com:*/*"
```

Comment: ok, I tried that and now I'm getting a different error: ERROR: Failed to check out {URL}
org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E175002: connection refused by the server
svn: E175002: OPTIONS request failed on {FOLDER}

Comment: This error most of time mean that you don't have access to repository.
chown issue (don't have access in file system) or could be httpd.conf issue

Answer (score 0):

Configure proxy configuration [in Hudson's settings](http://www.eclipse.org/hudson/the-hudson-book/book-hudson.html#section-plugin-management-advanced).
`Dsvnkit.http.sslProtocols` and `Dsvnkit.http.methods=Basic,Digest,Negotiate,NTLM` have nothing to do with proxy authentication in your case.

Comment: I've configured my proxy settings there, clicked the test button and the test succeeded. I've also been able to download plugins successfully, but SVN still can't authenticate.